# Visual studio ClickOne : clickone certificate is not found in the store

Tags: c#

I cloned c # project on github but when i want to run it does not work.

**Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion status
Error Unable to find the manifest signing certificate in the certificate store. Scool-cash-manager**

how to solve this error ?

Comment: You can generate your certificate from ClickOnce IHM in Visual Studio.

Comment: ...just because the code was sourced from github doesn't make it a `github` problem

Comment: i solve the problem with the answer of @vernou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*i solve the problem by* : **generating your certificate from ClickOnce IHM in Visual Studio.**